# Rails 4 - ActiveAdmin - Redactor - Heroku -- has no method 'redactor' console error

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, redactor

I've been trying to tackle this all morning. Locally, this setup works just fine. I am not using the redactor-rails gem because this is a rails 4 app and it doesn't support it. I have moved the redactor.css and redactor.js calls from the active_admin initializer file to be required in my actice_admin.js.coffee and active_admin.css files because on Heroku, it could not find the path. Now, when firing up the page that should be displaying redactor, I get `has no method 'redactor'` in the console.

I'm at a loss. I've read up on precompiling assets and the how the pipeline works, but it doesn't seem like I'm doing anything out of the ordinary here.

So how can I deploy to Heroku without this error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I seemed to have disregarded an important task. After thinking about precompilation a bit more I remembered I had been told to run

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

before. After running that again, it precompiled the active_admin.css and active_admin.js.coffee files which had the new `require`'s in it. Viola!

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Better yet, Heroku will precompile all assets for you (and you won't have to store them in the git repo) if you remove any existing precompiled assets from /public/assets.  Cheers!

Comment: @Donovan you are right. And that's actually the correct method. For whatever reason, Redactor was not showing with a regular deployment to Heroku. My approach must have fixed something. So I deleted my public/assets contents so my local app wouldn't read those stylesheets, etc. first.